# How to add and execute another function when the button, having initial function, is pressed again using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

so...I am coding one of my very first projects on my own. It is a program that checks whether a year you typed is a leap year or not, using Tkinter. So here's the program:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

def check():
    global year
    year = entry_1.get()
    try:
        YEAR = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel(title = "Invalid input", message = "You can only use whole numbers.")
    if YEAR%4 == 0:
        if YEAR%100 == 0:
            if YEAR%400 == 0:
                result_1 = tk.Label(window, text = f"{YEAR} is a leap year.", font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
                result_1.pack()
            else:
                result_2 = tk.Label(window, text = f"{YEAR} is not a leap year.", font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
                result_2.pack()
        else:
            result_3 = tk.Label(window, text = f"{YEAR} is a leap year.", font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
            result_3.pack()
    else:
        result_4 = tk.Label(window, text = f"{YEAR} is not a leap year.", font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
        result_4.pack()



window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Leap year Checker")
window.resizable(0, 0)

window.geometry("500x350")

label_0 = tk.Label(window, text = "Leap Year Checker", font = ("Verdana", 20, "bold underline"), anchor = "center")
label_0.pack()

label_1 = tk.Label(window, text = "Enter the year: ", font = ("Times", 20), anchor = "center")
label_1.pack()

entry_1 = tk.Entry(window, text = "YYYY", width = 15)
entry_1.pack()

year = 0

button_1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Check", anchor = "e", command = check)
button_1.place(x = 320, y = 72)

window.mainloop()
```

The program works perfectly until you give the input for the second time which, instead of overwriting the first output, is displayed just below the first output. So I am thinking of adding another function, say clear() to clear the first output, into the check() function itself. So that whenever I press the button with check() once again, it clears the first and the second output is overwritten.
But I don't know how to do that using Tkinter. I tried adding a function called clear() with the result label as the parameter and added a condition if check() == true so that when check button is pressed, the clear() will be executed as well, and I added some condition from which time the output should start overwriting so that it will clear the initial output as soon as next input is added on pressing the button, and not the first input. And when I run the code, and press the check button, it runs into an error for infinity.

I searched for solutions but I guess the wording of the question is the only problem why I don't get the exact solution.

So can you suggest to me how to add another function into the button when that button is pressed, so that it will clear the initial output and the next output is displayed, and at the same time doesn't run into an error for infinity when giving the condition for pressing the button.

PS. since I'm a beginner. I would love to hear suggestions and tips to make my code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Instead change the function, to make it so that the label appears only once but keeps changing. Look at my answer!

Comment: Thanks, it really fixed the issue! I didn't think to put the result label outside the function and just configure it inside. Once, again thank you so much. It now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `result_1, ...`, just make one label and change it using `.config()  method` in the main code

```
result = tk.Label(window, text = '' , font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
result.pack() # This is not under function
```

Then change function `check()`

```
def check():
    global result
    global year
    year = entry_1.get()
    try:
        YEAR = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel(title = "Invalid input", message = "You can only use whole numbers.")
    if YEAR%4 == 0:
        if YEAR%100 == 0:
            if YEAR%400 == 0:
                result.configure(text=f"{YEAR} is a leap year.")
            else:
                result.configure(text=f"{YEAR} is not a leap year.")
        else:
            result.configure(text=f"{YEAR} is a leap year.")
    else:
        result.configure(text=f"{YEAR} is not leap year.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `.config()`. It allows to configure all the parameters of the specified widget. You can pack the label without any text, and then use `.config(text=...)`. Also, it is better to calculate inside the `try:` block because whenever a `ValueError` is raised, `YEAR` is not defined. And that will, in fact raise a `UnboundLocalError`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

def check():
    global year
    year = entry_1.get()
    try:
        YEAR = int(year)
        if YEAR%4 == 0:
            if YEAR%100 == 0:
                if YEAR%400 == 0:
                    
                    result_1.config(text=f"{YEAR} is a leap year.")
                else:
                    result_1.config(text=f"{YEAR} is not a leap year.")
            else:
                result_1.config(text=f"{YEAR} is a leap year.")
        else:
            result_1.config(text=f"{YEAR} is not a leap year.")

    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel(title = "Invalid input", message = "You can only use whole numbers.")
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Leap year Checker")

window.resizable(0, 0)
window.geometry("500x350")

label_0 = tk.Label(window, text = "Leap Year Checker", font = ("Verdana", 20, "bold underline"), anchor = "center")
label_0.pack()

label_1 = tk.Label(window, text = "Enter the year: ", font = ("Times", 20), anchor = "center")
label_1.pack()

entry_1 = tk.Entry(window, text = "YYYY", width = 15)
entry_1.pack()

year = 0

button_1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Check", anchor = "e", command = check)
button_1.place(x = 320, y = 72)
result_1 = tk.Label(window, font = ("Times", 30, "bold"))
result_1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much too! It fixed the output issue. So I can use configure() to overwrite the previous output. And also didn't think about calculating inside the try block. However, I did get the UnboundLocalError. But after some code revisions, I didn't get the error. But this looks much correct as it would prevent from future bugs.